# Grid search with f1 as scoring function,implementation error?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm training MLP and using version 0.18dev of sklearn. I don't know what's wrong with my code. Could you guys please help?

```
# TODO: Import 'GridSearchCV' and 'make_scorer'
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

# TODO: Create the parameters list you wish to tune       
parameters = {'max_iter' : [100,200]}

# TODO: Initialize the classifier
clf = clf_B

# TODO: Make an f1 scoring function using 'make_scorer' 
f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score, pos_label = 'Yes')

# TODO: Perform grid search on the classifier using the f1_scorer as the scoring method
grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf,parameters,scoring = f1_scorer)

# TODO: Fit the grid search object to the training data and find the optimal parameters
grid_obj = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Get the estimator
clf = grid_obj.best_estimator_

# Report the final F1 score for training and testing after parameter tuning
print "Tuned model has a training F1 score of {:.4f}.".format(predict_labels(clf, X_train, y_train))
print "Tuned model has a testing F1 score of {:.4f}.".format(predict_labels(clf, X_test, y_test))
```

And the error message

```
---
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-216-4a3fb1d65cb7> in <module>()
     24 
     25 # TODO: Fit the grid search object to the training data and find the optimal parameters
---> 26 grid_obj = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)
     27 
     28 # Get the estimator

/home/indy/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    810 
    811         """
--> 812         return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
    813 
    814 

/home/indy/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in _fit(self, X, y, parameter_iterable)
    537                                  'of samples (%i) than data (X: %i samples)'
    538                                  % (len(y), n_samples))
--> 539         cv = check_cv(cv, X, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
    540 
    541         if self.verbose > 0:

/home/indy/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.pyc in check_cv(cv, X, y, classifier)
   1726         if classifier:
   1727             if type_of_target(y) in ['binary', 'multiclass']:
-> 1728                 cv = StratifiedKFold(y, cv)
   1729             else:
   1730                 cv = KFold(_num_samples(y), cv)

/home/indy/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.pyc in __init__(self, y, n_folds, shuffle, random_state)
    546         for test_fold_idx, per_label_splits in enumerate(zip(*per_label_cvs)):
    547             for label, (_, test_split) in zip(unique_labels, per_label_splits):
--> 548                 label_test_folds = test_folds[y == label]
    549                 # the test split can be too big because we used
    550                 # KFold(max(c, self.n_folds), self.n_folds) instead of

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

MLPClassifier and this is how my input looks like.

```
clf_B = MLPClassifier(random_state=4)

print X_train

     school_GP  school_MS  sex_F  sex_M  age  address_R  address_U  \
171        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   16        0.0        1.0   
12         1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   15        0.0        1.0   
13         1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   15        0.0        1.0   
151        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   16        0.0        1.0   
310        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   19        0.0        1.0   
274        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   17        0.0        1.0   
371        0.0        1.0    0.0    1.0   18        1.0        0.0   
29         1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   16        0.0        1.0   
109        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   16        0.0        1.0   
327        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   17        1.0        0.0   
131        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   15        0.0        1.0   
128        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   18        1.0        0.0   
174        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   16        0.0        1.0   
108        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   15        1.0        0.0   
280        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   17        0.0        1.0   
163        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   17        0.0        1.0   
178        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   16        1.0        0.0   
275        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   17        0.0        1.0   
35         1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   15        0.0        1.0   
276        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   18        1.0        0.0   
282        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   18        1.0        0.0   
99         1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   16        0.0        1.0   
194        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   16        0.0        1.0   
357        0.0        1.0    1.0    0.0   17        0.0        1.0   
10         1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   15        0.0        1.0   
112        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   16        0.0        1.0   
338        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   18        0.0        1.0   
292        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   18        0.0        1.0   
305        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   18        0.0        1.0   
340        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   19        0.0        1.0   
..         ...        ...    ...    ...  ...        ...        ...   
255        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   17        0.0        1.0   
58         1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   15        0.0        1.0   
33         1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   15        0.0        1.0   
38         1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   15        1.0        0.0   
359        0.0        1.0    1.0    0.0   18        0.0        1.0   
51         1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   15        0.0        1.0   
363        0.0        1.0    1.0    0.0   17        0.0        1.0   
260        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   18        0.0        1.0   
102        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   15        0.0        1.0   
195        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   17        0.0        1.0   
167        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   16        0.0        1.0   
293        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   17        1.0        0.0   
116        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   15        0.0        1.0   
124        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   16        0.0        1.0   
218        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   17        0.0        1.0   
287        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   17        0.0        1.0   
319        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   18        0.0        1.0   
47         1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   16        0.0        1.0   
213        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   18        0.0        1.0   
389        0.0        1.0    1.0    0.0   18        0.0        1.0   
95         1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   15        1.0        0.0   
162        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   16        0.0        1.0   
263        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   17        0.0        1.0   
360        0.0        1.0    1.0    0.0   18        1.0        0.0   
75         1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   15        0.0        1.0   
299        1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   18        0.0        1.0   
22         1.0        0.0    0.0    1.0   16        0.0        1.0   
72         1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   15        1.0        0.0   
15         1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   16        0.0        1.0   
168        1.0        0.0    1.0    0.0   16        0.0        1.0   

     famsize_GT3  famsize_LE3  Pstatus_A    ...     higher  internet  \
171          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
12           0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
13           1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
151          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         0   
310          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         0   
274          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
371          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          0         1   
29           1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
109          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
327          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
131          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
128          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
174          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
108          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
280          0.0          1.0        1.0    ...          1         1   
163          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          0         1   
178          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
275          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
35           1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         0   
276          1.0          0.0        1.0    ...          0         1   
282          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         0   
99           1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
194          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
357          0.0          1.0        1.0    ...          1         0   
10           1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
112          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
338          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
292          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
305          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
340          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
..           ...          ...        ...    ...        ...       ...   
255          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
58           0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
33           0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
38           1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
359          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
51           0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
363          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
260          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
102          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
195          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
167          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
293          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         0   
116          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         0   
124          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
218          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         0   
287          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
319          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
47           1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
213          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
389          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         0   
95           1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
162          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         0   
263          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         0   
360          0.0          1.0        1.0    ...          1         0   
75           1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
299          0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
22           0.0          1.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
72           1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
15           1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   
168          1.0          0.0        0.0    ...          1         1   

     romantic  famrel  freetime  goout  Dalc  Walc  health  absences  
171         1       4         3      2     1     1       3         2  
12          0       4         3      3     1     3       5         2  
13          0       5         4      3     1     2       3         2  
151         1       4         4      4     3     5       5         6  
310         1       4         2      4     2     2       3         0  
274         1       4         3      3     1     1       1         2  
371         1       4         3      3     2     3       3         3  
29          1       4         4      5     5     5       5        16  
109         1       5         4      5     1     1       4         4  
327         0       4         4      5     5     5       4         8  
131         1       4         3      3     1     2       4         0  
128         0       3         3      3     1     2       4         0  
174         0       4         4      5     1     1       4         4  
108         1       1         3      5     3     5       1         6  
280         1       4         5      4     2     4       5        30  
163         0       5         3      3     1     4       2         2  
178         1       4         3      3     3     4       3        10  
275         1       4         4      4     2     3       5         6  
35          0       3         5      1     1     1       5         0  
276         1       4         1      1     1     1       5        75  
282         0       5         2      2     1     1       3         1  
99          0       5         3      5     1     1       3         0  
194         0       5         3      3     1     1       3         0  
357         1       1         2      3     1     2       5         2  
10          0       3         3      3     1     2       2         0  
112         0       3         1      2     1     1       5         6  
338         0       5         3      3     1     1       1         7  
292         1       5         4      3     1     1       5        12  
305         0       4         4      3     1     1       3         8  
340         1       4         3      4     1     3       3         4  
..        ...     ...       ...    ...   ...   ...     ...       ...  
255         0       4         4      4     1     2       5         2  
58          0       4         3      2     1     1       5         2  
33          0       5         3      2     1     1       2         0  
38          0       4         3      2     1     1       5         2  
359         0       5         3      2     1     1       4         0  
51          0       4         3      3     1     1       5         2  
363         1       2         3      4     1     1       1         0  
260         1       3         1      2     1     3       2        21  
102         0       5         3      3     1     1       5         4  
195         1       4         3      2     1     1       5         0  
167         1       4         2      3     1     1       3         0  
293         0       3         1      2     1     1       3         6  
116         0       4         4      3     1     1       2         2  
124         1       5         4      4     1     1       5         0  
218         0       3         3      3     1     4       3         3  
287         0       4         3      3     1     1       3         6  
319         0       4         4      4     3     3       5         2  
47          0       4         2      2     1     1       2         4  
213         0       4         4      4     2     4       5        15  
389         0       1         1      1     1     1       5         0  
95          0       3         1      2     1     1       1         2  
162         0       4         4      4     2     4       5         0  
263         0       3         2      3     1     1       4         4  
360         1       4         3      4     1     4       5         0  
75          0       4         3      3     2     3       5         6  
299         1       1         4      2     2     2       1         5  
22          0       4         5      1     1     3       5         2  
72          1       3         3      4     2     4       5         2  
15          0       4         4      4     1     2       2         4  
168         0       5         1      5     1     1       4         0  

[300 rows x 48 columns]
```

This is how my output looks like

```
print y_train

    passed
171    yes
12     yes
13     yes
151    yes
310     no
274    yes
371    yes
29     yes
109    yes
327    yes
131     no
128     no
174     no
108    yes
280     no
163    yes
178     no
275    yes
35      no
276     no
282    yes
99      no
194    yes
357    yes
10      no
112    yes
338    yes
292    yes
305    yes
340    yes
..     ...
255     no
58      no
33     yes
38     yes
359    yes
51     yes
363    yes
260    yes
102    yes
195    yes
167    yes
293    yes
116    yes
124     no
218     no
287    yes
319    yes
47     yes
213     no
389     no
95     yes
162     no
263     no
360    yes
75     yes
299    yes
22     yes
72      no
15     yes
168     no

[300 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: I would like to help but the code you provided does not yield the error you mentioned? Can you change the code such that the error occurs when I compile?

Comment: You did also not define f1_score. The code you provided seems to be some sort of template (see TODO comments) which can't possibly run without filling it with the necessary definitions.

Comment: Which version of sklearn are you using?

Comment: I use 0.14.1 and I know that MLPClassifier is not yet supported in this version. So I tried it with a RandomForestClassifier. But without f1_score defined, the following fails: f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score, pos_label = 'Yes')

Comment: Did you try to fix make_scorer? remove pos_label it should work

Comment: According to the sklearn documentation, make_scorer consumes a score function as mandatory first argument. This is f1_score in your case. This variable is however not defined in your code. Please restart you python kernel/python IDE. Then copy past the code you provided and run it. You will see that many variables are not defined and that your code does not yield the error you mentioned. This makes it very hard to help you since we are not talking about the same problem.

Comment: @Ohumeronen, the issue is 'IndexError: too many indices for array'

Comment: @NabihIbrahimBawazir I know but can you reproduce this error? I couldn't... Btw the post is almost 3 years old now.

Comment: I already have the solution